# Stripe.Net 21.4.1 removed 'List' method from 'BalanceService' object

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

I upgraded my Stripe.Net nuget package for .Net from 19.+ to 21.4.1 but after I did this I had to make numerous changes to my code. One change I had to make was dropping all the Stripe from object names.

ex. StripeBalanceService -> BalanceService

when I did this I noticed that the 'BalanceService' object lost the 'List' method! I still see it in the [Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance/balance_history)

Am I missing something here in terms of packages or updates?
Or did Stripe just screw me!?

Here is a screen shot that shows the missing method

[image]

And here is a drop down of what's available for the 'BalanceService' object.

[image]

Here is the code where I'm calling the method

```
    private static void GetBalanceTranactionIds(string payoutId, ref List<string> balanceTransactionIds, string startingAfter)
    {
        var service = new BalanceService();
        var balanceOptions = new BalanceTransactionListOptions { Limit =100, PayoutId = payoutId };

        if (startingAfter != null)
            balanceOptions.StartingAfter = startingAfter;

        List<BalanceTransaction> balanceTransactions = service.List(balanceOptions);

        balanceTransactionIds.AddRange(balanceTransactions.Select(i => i.Id).ToList());

        if (balanceTransactions.Count() == 100)
            GetBalanceTranactionIds(payoutId, ref balanceTransactionIds, balanceTransactions.Last().Id);
    }
```

Here is the BalanceService object with no List.

```
public class BalanceService : Service<Balance>, ISingletonRetrievable<Balance>
{
    public BalanceService();
    public BalanceService(string apiKey);

    public override string BasePath { get; }

    public virtual Balance Get(RequestOptions requestOptions = null);
    public virtual Task<Balance> GetAsync(RequestOptions requestOptions = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
}
```

Comment: would you be able to post code instead of images/pictures?

Comment: Stripe.net v20 is a major upgrade of the library. There are quite number of broken changes when upgrading from older version including removing the `Stripe` prefix

You can refer to https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/blob/master/v20_migration_guide.md for the upgrading guide

Comment: Hi wsw, maybe I read through the page quickly but I don't see anything about deprecated methods like the one I posted! Is there something in the page I missed regarding my post? Additionally in the API docs I still see a .List() method.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like BalanceTransaction functionalities have been extracted from BalanceService.cs and moved to its own class.
You can do something like

```
var service = new BalanceTransactionService();
var balanceOptions = new BalanceTransactionListOptions { Limit = 100, PayoutId = payoutId }; 
service.BalanceTransactionService.ListAsync(balanceOptions);
```

Reference for change: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/commit/9c6e4e3c213fb8064e625a8e53b9bd306e641d6a#diff-3cef216515aac44aeefa3ba55153f755

Comment: Instead of a link, please provide code in your answer.

Comment: Sure @DeathWaltz. Updated the answer. I saw the link to the commit that made the change useful for context. Thanks!